# Fixed div related to its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this snippet, but I need to make the red box be limited to the white box not transpacing.

```css
.main {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1250px;
  position: relative;
}

.container{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 650px;
  background: white;
}

.red-box{
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 140px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="red-box">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does `red-box` have fixed **width** and **height**?

Comment: @Gemma that will be a button and I have fixed width and height.

Comment: @ThiagFerreira so what's the requirement?

Comment: @kukkuz I don't know how to make the red box just stay inside the white box when scroll down

Comment: How about making the white box fixed instead of the red one?

Comment: @Winter because that div is an aside div and absolute on the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `red-box` is `fixed` already, make your `container` fixed too- hope this solves your problem. Cheers!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1250px;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  height: 650px;
  background: white;
}
.red-box {
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 140px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="red-box">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:

Hope this pins it- the `red-div` scrolls out along with the `container` using jquery:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var wrapper = $('.container');
  var box = $('.red-box');

  var offset = wrapper.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() + wrapper.outerHeight() - box.outerHeight();


  if (offset >= 0) {
    box.css({
      'top': 0
    });
    return;
  }

  box.offset({
    'left': box.offset().left,
    'top': $(window).scrollTop() + offset
  });


});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1250px;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 650px;
  background: white;
}
.red-box {
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 140px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="red-box">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just the red-box need to be fixed, imagine an footer that will transpacin the footer and will not work this need to be limited to the white-box cause this is only an aside div, sorry for my english.

Comment: try `position: absolute` for both `container` and `red-box`?

Comment: When I try this the `red-box` always stay on the top

Comment: so when the `container` scrolls to the top, you want the `red-box` to go with it?

Comment: Yes he need to go with it when scroll, but no transpacin the `white-box`

Comment: have added a solution- please check if this is what you needed?